# File size of a >4gb file?

Tags: c++

In MSVC I ran the following code. a gives me -1, b gives me EINVAL and c gives me 0. When the path is a file that can fit in a 32bit value this function works fine. How do I get the length of a file >4gb?

```
f = fopen(path.c_str(), "r+b");
printf("f=%X\n", f);
auto a = fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
auto b = errno;
auto c = ftell(f);
```

Comment: Normally to get the file size you use `stat` (MSVC may spell it `_stat`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSVC has 64 bit variants of most C stdlib file functions which allow you to work with files larger that 4GB, in your case, see [`_ftelli64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ys3hc0b.aspx). There is also [`_filelengthi64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfbc2kec.aspx) for descriptors (which you can get using `_fileno`).

Answer (score 2):

The POSIX API uses [`lseek`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) which takes a `off_t` argument.

Windows API uses [`SetFilePointerEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365542(v=vs.85).aspx) which takes a `LARGE_INTEGER` argument.

And @Necrolis told you the clib MSVC extension...

Answer (score 0):

`boost::file_size` returns the largest available integer type, so *at least* 64 bits. Works on all major platforms.